# Trying to Get Firebase Working from a Plunker

Tags: firebase, plunker

I've added [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co) to the list of domains that my Firebase is authorized to receive inquiries from, but my efforts to either read or write data to/from Firebase from a Plunker are not succeeding. Is there a security reason that would prevent Plunkers from being able to interact with Firebase?

Comment: [Engineer @ Firebase] Can you provide a code snippet or Plunker link that illustrates the problem you're seeing? Happy to help debug!

Comment: Is it advisable for me to include the URL of my own Firebase?  My problem is that the functionality seems to work (in that I can put things into it and read them back out again), but they don't work across multiple clients at once and changes I make don't show up in my Firebase console . . .

Comment: If you'd like, you can leave out the URL of your own Firebase and share some code here. Alternatively, ping us privately at support@firebase.com!